# Подгрузка конфигов в beego

Tags: golang, beego

После сборки проекта на `beego` c помощью go `install`, запуская бинарник из папки bin получаю ошибку, что не найден файл конфига

> [config.go:314] [W] open /Users/ххх/conf/app.conf: no such file or
>   directory

Хотя некоторое время назад этот способ работал. Подскажите, как можно это исправить?

Comment: к примеру, создать этот файл. пустым.

Comment: Все дело в том что это файл есть в директории $GOPATH/src/мое_приложение.

Comment: может быть, `/Users/ххх/conf/` — это несколько не то же самое, что и `$GOPATH/src/мое_приложение`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приложение не может найти файлы шаблонов или конфигурации или же случается ошибка "nil pointer".

Это может быть связано с использованием go run main.go для запуска приложения. go run компилирует файл и складывает бинарник во временную папку. Но Beego нуждается в файлах статики, шаблонах и конфигурационных файлах, которые лежат не во временной папке, а в папке вашего приложения. Так что вам нужно использовать go build и запускать обязательно из папки вашего приложения, для примера: ./app. Или вы можете испольвать bee run app